# How to create JBPM job using custom java class?

Tags: asynchronous, jbpm, executor

I'm using **Jboss JBPM version 7.24**. I'm trying to create a job with a java class provided as part of a project imported in *JBPM Business Central*. The project is built/deployed successfully.

The job is created using UI, business-central->jobs-> New Job. In the UI, the fully qualified java class name is provided as "`org.jbpm.examples.cmd.UserCommand`".

However it gives this error:

> "Job must have valid class that defines Job Type"

.

If the job is created using "`org.jbpm.executor.commands.LogCleanupCommand`" part of jbpm-executor, it gets created successfully.

Please suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The job is defined by its class and Parameters. The class to define the type for you should be "`org.jbpm.executor.commands.LogCleanupCommand`"

What parameters do you put for LogCleanupCommand and is there a log details giving further indicators why it complains? Example parameters are:

> "SkipProcessLog", "false"
>
> "SkipTaskLog", "false"
>
> "SkipExecutorLog", "false"
>
> "SingleRun", "true"
>
> "ForProcess", processId
>
> "OlderThan", olderThan